# WSO2 IS 5.3.0. Tenant Domains drop-down list has only one value: super tenant

Tags: wso2-identity-server

In WSO2 IS v.5.3.0 I am getting the dropdown and only value I can see is super tenant. 
All configurations according to "Loading tenants into the dropdown in the login page of the authentication endpoint web application" has been made.
When I send request

https://:9443/dashboard

I get exception:

```
[2017-01-20 16:30:53,270] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.TenantMgtAdminServiceClient} -  Sending POST request to URL : https://172.16.159.102:9443/services//TenantMgtAdminService/retrieveTenantsfailed.
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://172.16.159.102:9443/services//TenantMgtAdminService/retrieveTenants
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.TenantMgtAdminServiceClient.sendPostRequest(TenantMgtAdminServiceClient.java:262)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.TenantDataManager.getServiceResponse(TenantDataManager.java:217)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.TenantDataManager.refreshActiveTenantDomainsList(TenantDataManager.java:258)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.TenantDataManager.getAllActiveTenantDomains(TenantDataManager.java:229)
        at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:403)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.filter.AuthenticationEndpointFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationEndpointFilter.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:72)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

There is a double slash "//". Why ?

In WSO2 IS v5.2.0 all worked OK.

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EndpointConfig.properties there is commented property:

## identity.server.serviceURL=https://localhost:9443/services/

I uncommented this:

identity.server.serviceURL=/services/

But closing slash is redundant. And therefore in request there were double slash.

I had to discover this before sending question